# d3.forceSimulation step through data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array of sets of data points that are represented by bubbles grouping and regrouping as I step through the array entries. Each step properly reflects the changes in the data but the bubbles from the previous step disappear and the new bubbles fly in to their new positions instead of transitioning from their previous positions. I have a feeling I'm doing something simple and stupid but I'm brand-new to D3js and can't seem to get it working...

Here's the first 3 steps of my data (massively shortened for readability):

```
data = [{"state_matrix":{"apps":null,"grade":null,"grades":
["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"],"nodes":
[{"grade_level":6,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1409},
{"grade_level":6,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1410},
{"grade_level":0,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1411},
{"grade_level":2,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1412},
{"grade_level":0,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1413},
{"grade_level":4,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1414},
{"grade_level":0,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1415},
{"grade_level":0,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1416},
{"grade_level":4,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1617}]}},
{"state_matrix":{"apps":null,"grade":"0","grades":
["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"],"nodes":
[{"grade_level":6,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1409},
{"grade_level":6,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1410},
{"grade_level":0,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":1,"id":1411},
{"grade_level":2,"score":2,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1412},
{"grade_level":0,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":1,"id":1413},
{"grade_level":4,"score":2,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1414},
{"grade_level":0,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":1,"id":1415},
{"grade_level":2,"score":2,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1616},
{"grade_level":4,"score":2,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1617}]}},
{"state_matrix":{"apps":null,"grade":"0","grades":
["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"],"nodes":
[{"grade_level":6,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1409},
{"grade_level":6,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1410},
{"grade_level":0,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":1,"id":1411},
{"grade_level":2,"score":2,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1412},
{"grade_level":0,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":1,"id":1413},
{"grade_level":4,"score":2,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1414},
{"grade_level":0,"score":0,"status":"pending","state":1,"id":1415},
{"grade_level":2,"score":2,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1616},
{"grade_level":4,"score":2,"status":"pending","state":0,"id":1617}]}}]
```

And my script [edited]:

```
<script>
  var canvas = $('#canvas');
  var width = canvas.width();
  var height = canvas.height();
  var c = d3.select('#canvas');

  var yCenter = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100];
  var xCenter = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100];
  var color = d3.schemeCategory20;
  var nodes = data[0].state_matrix.nodes;

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(.1))
    .force('x', d3.forceX(function(d) {
      return xCenter[d.score];
    }))
    .force('y', d3.forceY(function(d) {
      return yCenter[d.grade_level];
    }))
    .force('collision', d3.forceCollide()
        .radius(function(d) {
          return d.score+4;
    }))
    .on('tick', ticked);

  function ticked() {
    node.attr('cx', function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });
  }


  function draw(nodes) {

    node = c.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
      .style("fill", "blue")
      .attr('r', function(d) {
        return d.score+4;
      })
      .attr('cx', function(d) {
       return d.x;
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });

    node.exit().remove();


    node = node.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class","node")
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return color[d.state];
      })
      .merge(node)
      .attr('r', function(d) {
        return d.score+4;
      })
      .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });


    // Update and restart the simulation.
    simulation.nodes(nodes);
    simulation.alpha(1).restart();
  }


  function start(counter){
    if(counter < data.length){
      setTimeout(function(){

        nodes = data[counter].state_matrix.nodes;
        draw(nodes);

        counter++;
        start(counter);
      }, 3000);
    }
  }

  draw(nodes);
  start(1);
</script>
```

How do I get each node to transition from its previous state to its new state from step-to-step instead of flying in fresh from 0,0 each time?

Comment: Have you tried using the "id" value as the key to your data? Not tested, but something like `.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });`

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference, but didn't break it either so you may be on to something. I'll try looking further down that rabbit hole. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing I need to do something with `d.fx` and `d.fy` but, for the life of me I can't figure out how or where without it breaking everything.